# What is the value of integration over zero to infinity of $exp^{-x^n}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

What is general formulation of an integration i.e., $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n} dx$.
Well I did some calculation but the answer is wrong, but am not getting where did I got wrong.[image: please check out the solution I did]

But if that's correct, it doesn't work for anything except $n=1$.

Comment: So you make the substitution $y = \sqrt{x}$, so $dx = 2ydy$. Then the integral becomes $\int_0^{\infty} 2ye^{-y^{2n}}dy$, which is not what you have written.

Comment: The substitution $y=x^n$ yields $dy=nx^{n-1}dx$ hence $dx=y^{1/n-1}dy/n$ and your integral is $\int_0^\infty y^{1/n-1}e^{-y}dy/n=\Gamma(1/n)/n=\Gamma(1+1/n)$.

Comment: Sorry didnt got your point, where did I got wrong again?

Comment: I thought functions of this form didn't have closed-form integral.

Comment: Yeah I got it already, and found solution as gamma {(1+n)/n}

Comment: Yeah I got it already, and found solution as gamma {(1+n)/n}

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that
$e^{-x^n}
=e^{-y^{n/2}}
$,
not
$e^{-y}$.

Comment: Yeah I got it already, and found solution as gamma {(1+n)/n}

Comment: I like to write that as (1/n)!